# Converting normal layout to xlarge layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using below xml layout for rendering in normal layout.
But when I try to run in the xlarge screens like ASUS transformer(Honeycomb or Ice Cream Sandwich) the image for Image Button takes images from drawable-mdpi resource folder. Even tried with change the layout and the bigger images for buttons for large screens but the same mdpi image renders.

Could anybody give me some pointers on how to solve this problem. thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/white"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:tileMode="repeat" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:weightSum="3">

     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView 
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
          <ImageView 
            android:src="@drawable/logo1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/buttonMainBackClosetheApp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:tileMode="repeat"/>
     </LinearLayout>

         </LinearLayout>   







<LinearLayout 
android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="3" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15px">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtnFindUs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnFindUs"
            android:src="@drawable/findus_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white" />
        <TextView 
            android:text="Find Us" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnCatalog"
            android:src="@drawable/catalog_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Catalog" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnMyContact"
            android:src="@drawable/mycontact_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/white"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="My" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Contacts" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnPhoto"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/white"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="Photo" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton 
            android:src="@drawable/myaccount_icon"
            android:id="@+id/btnMyAccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/white"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="My Account" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnFeedback"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white"
            android:src="@drawable/feedback_icon" />

        <TextView 
            android:text="Feedback" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20px"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- dont change the above value of 45px in 
    android:layout_marginBottom="45px"-->

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnPromotions"
            android:src="@drawable/promotion_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white" />
        <TextView 
            android:text="Promotions" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnTradeTools"
            android:src="@drawable/tradetools_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/white" />
        <TextView 
            android:text="Trade Tools" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/btnClientInfo"
            android:src="@drawable/clientinfo_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/white"/>
        <TextView 
            android:text="About" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#e4e4e4"
        android:tileMode="repeat">
<include layout="@layout/footer_include_layout"/>




         </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transformer has a ~160dpi, which makes it an mdpi screen. So it's only natural, that resources are loaded from mdpi folder

Comment: thanks. can you give me any pointers on how to enhance or set bigger images for 160dpi screens.

Comment: thanks, so it means I have to written one more layout with same name, which should take images from drawable-xlarge folder and image name is different than it is stored in drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi folders, but the emulator for 2.7 has density of 120 and when I run from these emulator it takes images from drawable-xlarge, is their other way to control rendering, for small screens small images and for big screen should render bigger images.